# How to assign option value for select after ajaxcall

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this html:

```
<select id="test"></select>
```

And This ajax code:

```
<script>
function get(name){
if(name=(new RegExp('[?&]'+encodeURIComponent(name)+'=([^&]*)')).exec(location.search))
  return decodeURIComponent(name[1]);
}

//url: localhost/web/index.php?name='whatever'
var value = get('name');

$(document).ready(function(){
$('select').select2();  

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: 'getValues.php',
data: {'test': $("#test").val(),'isAjax':true},
dataType:'json',
success: function(data) {

   var select = $("#test"), options = '';
   select.empty();      
   for(var i=0;i<data.length; i++)
   {
    options += "<option value='"+data[i].id+"'>"+ data[i].name +"</option>";   
   }

   select.append(options);
}
});
});
</script>
```

I need to set the value of select as taken from the url,which is (var value).
The value is working fine,as I tested it in alert.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are its the AJAX that is causing the issue. you need to trim() the response to remove a whitespace at the end of the returned data. Try the following :

```
success: function(data) {
   var response = data.trim(), select = $("#test"), options = '';
   select.empty();      
   for(var i=0;i<response.length; i++)
   {
    options += "<option value='"+response[i].id+"'>"+ response[i].name +"</option>";   
   }

   select.append(options).val(value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1) You can use `.val()` after appending options:

```
select.append(options);
select.val(value);
```

2)
or add attribute selected to option having same value while building the options html string.

```
options += "<option value='"+data[i].id+"' "+(data[i].id == value ? "selected" : "") +">"+ data[i].name +"</option>";
```

Comment: please debug the code. also check for error in console.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved.

The problem was that the returned value has space,which is taken from url as +
So I replaced "+" by " "

Thanks all !

Comment: this would be why I suggested .trim())  - to remove the space